# What does an InvocationTargetException caused by a ExceptionInitializerError mean in java?

Tags: java, runtime-error

In the past couple of weeks, I've started to take up java again.

My recent java project involves taking business data from a website (phone number, address, company name, etc.), sorting through it, and inserting the data into an excel file on the user's desktop. I am not using this for anything (just to get back in the flow), but I might try something similar for financial market data. Anyways, the code itself works fine if I run it from the .jar file or through Eclipse.

However, when I try to create an executable file (through launch4j) and run it, it wasn't properly running as the jar file had. So I created another .exe file and changed it from GUI to console to debug the problem. I've listed the problem below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:548)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.isTransformationAvailable(SSLCipher.java:510)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.<init>(SSLCipher.java:499)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.<clinit>(SSLCipher.java:82)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.<clinit>(CipherSuite.java:69)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuites(SSLContextImpl.java:343)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:556)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1844)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1820)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:184)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:110)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:83)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:334)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:291)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
        at java.base/java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1101)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.createConnection(HttpConnection.java:892)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:729)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:707)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:297)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:286)
        at SpiderTest.main(SpiderTest.java:64)
```

Looking through my code, it seems that the error occurs at Line 64, which is:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

I've tried all other solutions on StackOverflow and other sites, and none of them seem to fix this issue.  The main jar files I've used are Jsoup (for web) and Apache (for excel). I exported the excel project as a runnable jar file and packaged all required libraries into the generated jar. I'm at a loss on where to go, or if I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to just post this as a comment, but there is just a little too much text.  The Java exception `ExceptionInInitializerError` has been thrown (in my experience) whenever a `static` initializer is throwing an exception (for whatever reason) when the **Class Loader** attempts to load a particular class.  If this doesn't make sense, yet, look up the term **Static Initializer** on the Sun Documentation Websites, or look up it up on Stack Overflow or Google.  A **Static Initializer** is a part of a Java Class that is called whenever a class is first loaded into memory - it is surrounded by the `{` and `}` squiggly braces, but doesn't have a method name.

I've written (Quite a bit) of Java, but I don't know if a constructor could cause this, since most of my classes are `static classes`.

Now, to summarize so far, all that the "Caused By" says is that the class loader tried to load a class named `Cipher` using the method `javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:548)` and it couldn't load that class.

When this exception threw, you got a `InvokationTargetException` - which I am also ***very familiar*** with and that one is much easier to explain... Because the ***Class Loader*** *could not load the class mentioned by the previous exception,* when the line of code that you have called tried to get an instance of that class, it was unable to - *obviously because it could not even load the class from the **JAR File** in the first place.*

Last point, if you are running code from some class file - wherever you are running it from - and it is unable to load the **JSoup JAR File**, perhaps this is causing it.  I mean, if you are building executables, you need to figure out whether or not this executable can see the **JSoup JAR File** in the `CLASSPATH` Environment Variable.

Thoughts:

- First, if you ever put an addendum (in your question) explaining what you mean by `executable` I would be less confused because I have not made one before.  I have only made `executable .jar files`
- Does your `JAR File` contain the **JSoup** Classes?
- Did you set the `CLASSPATH` when you run this executable?
- Are you using the right **JDK** - one that contains this `class Cipher` - which is clearly needed by the **JSoup JAR**?  (Since it is failing to load `javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance()`)... Not all **JDK's** have access to `class javax.crypto.Cipher`
- Sometimes multiple **JDK's** can be installed on them, and not all of them have access to the same libraries.

There could be other reasons...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand what you're saying with the exceptionInitializer, but like you, I also have only static classes in my program. I also made an executable .jar file through launch4j. Ask for the JDK, I bundled the JDK (14.0.1) that I used to run the code in eclipse into the launch4j. I'm assuming since the code ran in eclipse and the JSoup class is in the classpath that it should work when I exported the project into a runnable jar file. However, I don't know if the .exe can see the JSoup Jar file in my classpath. Is there a way to check that?

Comment: After posting my answer, I noticed the `launch4j` part...  Um... I have been coding **Java** everyday for several years now.  The truth is I gave up on `.exe` files.  After thinking about this, I remember attempting to use `launch4j` - and not being able to get it to work.  That was a few years ago.  I write a library, and don't need an executable, so I'm sorry I cannot be of help.  I wouldn't know where to start with `launch4j` ...  I just saw those exception names in your stack trace and because I have seen that millions of times in my code, I thought I'd write answer -Good luck **launch4j**

Comment: **Side Note:** I just bought ***yet another*** Windows Computer - and the government makes so many trap doors for installing ***any*** executable onto a **Microsoft Box** that I wouldn't be surprised if there is one built into the tool you just tried.  Not Kidding...  Have you read about **Microsoft Windows S Mode** yet?

Comment: You know I haven't really thought about Windows being the issue. I'll still try and work at it and see if there is anything I can do. But thanks. I learned quite a lot from your answer that I didn't even know before.

Comment: Update: I did it, I hope. I don't exactly know-how. I changed some classpath settings and reinstalled my jdk and it worked.